# Commercial or open source C++ TWAIN library for Windows

Tags: windows, c++

Please, recommend a library for a quik start. The task is to create a new scanning module for existing MFC-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [LEADTOOLS Twain scanning module](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/twain). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The following C++ code lets the user select a scanner and saves the scanned image to disk:

```
HTWAINSESSION twainSession = NULL;
APPLICATIONDATA appData = { sizeof(APPLICATIONDATA), hWnd, TEXT("My Company"), TEXT("My Product"), TEXT("1.0"), TEXT("My App"), TWLG_ENGLISH_USA, TWCY_USA };
L_TwainInitSession(&twainSession, &appData);
L_TwainSelectSource(twainSession, NULL);
BITMAPHANDLE bmp = { 0 };
L_TwainAcquire(twainSession, &bmp, sizeof(bmp), NULL, LTWAIN_SHOW_USER_INTERFACE, NULL, NULL);
if (bmp.Flags.Allocated)
{
   L_SaveBitmap(TEXT("g:\\test\\scannedImage.tif"), &bmp, FILE_TIFLZW, bmp.BitsPerPixel, 0, NULL);
   L_FreeBitmap(&bmp);
}
L_TwainEndSession(&twainSession);
```

There’s a free evaluation for the SDK on [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main). The evaluation contains advanced demos in case you need other Twain features (setting capabilities, scanning multiple images from a document feeder, etc.).
There’s also free email and chat support during evaluation.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info!
As I see, this SDK is included into multiple LEADTOOLS products... could you please give a hint which one to choose? TWAIN is the only thing I need at the moment.

Comment: Most Twain features are included in all imaging (non-Multimedia) toolkits, starting with the [Imaging Pro](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging-pro). The only feature that requires the more expensive [Document Imaging](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document-imaging) is “Fast Twain”, but it’s mainly needed for optimizing high-volume document scanning. [This page](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/product-comparison-chart) shows all features and toolkits in a clear table.